# Jquery Moving SelectBox with Append() or html() or text()

Tags: jquery, html, text, append, drop-down-menu

I have a selectbox under a hidden div, I did a function that when I click in some place the select box appears with the correct option, but it doesn't render well, the control don't work properly, this is the code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.NewDiv').click(function () {
        $(this).append($('#MySelectBox'));
        $('#MySelectBox').val($(this).attr('value'));
    });
});

<select id="MySelectBox>
    <option...
</select>
```

I tried with append, html and text, all of them render the select box but it doesn't work properly proved on Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give the exact code and an example of how it isn't working?

Comment: You can test it here http://jsfiddle.net/XnWyY/3/ (try to select an option after moving it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this issue is because you're tying the event to the div, the same div that is now containing the select box. Therefore, when you select an option, it changes the option to '0' as it reads no value.

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/hghNJ/) fixes your issue.

Comment: @Korvin Szanto sorry i misunderstood the question.. Your solution is right +1

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see is that your current code puts the `select` into the `div`, and thus any click event on the `select` causes the operation to repeat.

Broken Example: http://jsfiddle.net/XnWyY/

Perhaps this is what you are looking for (click to move `select` after `div`, append new `option`): http://jsfiddle.net/XnWyY/1/

Or click to show, append new `option`: http://jsfiddle.net/XnWyY/2/

Comment: You can see the problem in the firs example, if you click the combobox before moving it works correctly but if you move the combo and then click on it, it changed you behavior. Try to click on "Fighter" after moving combobox here http://jsfiddle.net/XnWyY/3/

Answer (score 0):

Change your line with the below.

```
$(this).append($('#MySelectBox').html());
```

Comment: This is good if OP wants to add it several times. I suspect he only meant to make it visible once...

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler to have the div hidden, and then show() it once the trigger is clicked. The relevant code is in http://jsfiddle.net/L67LT/1/

```
$('#MySelectBox').hide();
var externalValue="Fighter";
$(function () {
    $('#newDiv').click(function () {
        console.log("clicked!");
        var box = $('#MySelectBox');
        box.show(); box.val(externalValue);
    });
});
```

Note also that using `$(this).attr('value')` was failing (in this case, it is a reference to the `newDiv` div, which has no attribute called `value`).

Answer (score -1):

Sorry i guess i misunderstood the question fixed the code now:

```
$('#newDiv').click(function () {
    $(this).append($('#MySelectBox'));
    $('#MySelectBox').val($(this).attr('value'));
    $('#MySelectBox').bind("click", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/hghNJ/1/